# RAII equivalent for FIFO release order

Tags: c++, raii

RAII is quite comfortable and I am having difficulties to provide an equivalent design for resources that must be released in the same order they were acquired (FIFO) as opposed to in the reverse order (Stack) that naturally come out of RAII.

In my specific case, I have a `stream` class as follow:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class stream {
  ...
public:
  // Producer API
  T& write_acquire(); // This acquires a storage element and will "block"
                      // until a slot is available in the underlying resource
  void write_release(&T); // This releases the storage element, transferring the data to a consumer

  // Consumer API
  T& read_acquire(); // This acquires a storage element and will "block"
                     // until a slot has been write_release
  void read_release(&T); // This releases the storage element making it available
                         // for a potential future write_acquire
};
```

And I was thinking of providing a RAII-style helper:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class stream_wslot {
  stream<T> &s;
  T &slot;
public:
  stream_wslot(stream<T> &s) : s{s}, slot{s.write_acquire()} {}
  ~stream_wslot() { s.write_release(slot); }

  operator T&() { return slot; }
  T& operator=(T &val) { return slot = val; }
};
```

But the issue is the following usage will not behave correctly:

```cpp
void test(stream<float> &fifo) {
  stream_wslot even(fifo);
  stream_wslot odd(fifo);
  ... first ...
  ... second ...
  // releases odd !!!
  // releases even
}
```

That is, we will release the `odd` slot before we release the `even` slot. While I could add a "reordering" queue in the `stream` I was wondering if there was a "clean" way of generalizing RAII to those situations.

Comment: Don't give callers access to `T` directly, give them a `shared_ptr<Node<T>>`, and each node has a shared_ptr to the next node in the list.  Then, when the second pointer is destroyed, the Node will keep the T alive until the first pointer is also destroyed. Oh wait, the actual destructions still happen in the wrong order. Darn.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to use a `std::queue`? From what I've seen it destroys the contained elements in the order they where entered when it's destroyed itself.

Comment: This is subtle, but I think your type is violating the implied contract of a “resource”. And as such you *shouldn’t* treat it as a resource (instead, consider wrapping the whole transaction into its own resource, which is effectively what the comment and answer suggesting using a queue are doing).

Comment: Nonyme: Did you try any of the suggestions you got in the answers out?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did, your queue based solution is nice (from a readability point of view), but my situation is for embedded hardware so dynamic allocation is expensive/unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative that uses a [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) and works in C++11 and up:

```
#include <queue>

void test(stream<float> &fifo) {
    std::queue<stream_wslot> wslots;

  #if __cplusplus >= 201703L                             // C++17 and later:
    auto& even = wslots.emplace(fifo);
    auto& odd = wslots.emplace(fifo);
  #else                                                  // C++11 and C++14:
    auto& even = (wslots.emplace(fifo), wslots.front());    
    auto& odd = (wslots.emplace(fifo), wslots.front());
  #endif

    // work with even and odd ...
}
```

The element referenced by `even` is created first, then the element referenced by `odd`.

At scope end, the `std::queue` first releases the element referenced by `even` and then releases the element referenced by `odd`.

Comment: I accepted your answer because this is the one that looks the cleanest to me. But in reality it doesn't apply to my use case as I am on an embedded device (for which dynamic allocation is too expensive or not available).

Comment: @Nonyme Hmm, that's too bad and it's not really helping you then. The class in the queue only hold two references so I'd expect it to be fairly easy on the system. Perhaps you should go with the `std::optional` version that Sam showed then?

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::optional`, at a cost of very modest, minimal overhead provides more control over construction, and a well-defined destruction order. Which is exactly what you're looking for, here.

For example:

```
std::optional<stream_wslot> o_even;
std::optional<stream_wslot> o_odd;

o_odd.emplace(fifo);
o_even.emplace(fifo);

auto &even=*o_even;
auto &odd=*o_odd;
```

From this point on, existing code that uses `odd` and `even` will find it hard to tell the difference. And the grand total: `odd` gets constructed first, `even` gets constructed second. `odd` gets destroyed first, when leaving this scope, `even` gets destroyed second. Same effective construction and destruction order.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a queue running on another thread for implementing the FIFO logic asynchronously. If `wslot` objects are constructed with a reference to that queue, they can tell it to perform `write_release()` for them when they destruct, but perform a regular `write_acquire()` on construction, which would block if necessary.

(Alternatively, on construction, they could pass an `std::future` somewhere, and fulfill the promise by `write_release()`ing on destruction. But this is just vague hand-waving on my part).